# Ошибка при работе с typedef в qt

Tags: c++, qt, typedef

Решил написать самый простой код, чисто что бы попробовать использовать `typedef`, но в итоге у меня вышла ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так сделал. Пишу в QT.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef int Func (int, int);
int test (int c, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int c, b;
    cout << "\n Enter value c,b: \n";
    cout << ' ';
    cin >> c;
    cin >> b;
    Func func1;
    func1 = test(c,b);

    return a.exec();
}
int test (int c, int b){
    if (b>c)
        cout << b+c;
    else
        cout << c-b;
}
```

[image: скрин ошибок]

Comment: Что этот код вообще должен делать? Даже если бы typedef был правильным запись `func1 = test(c,b);` никак не может быть валидной.

Comment: та по факту ничего, я пробую через typedef сделать указатель на функцию, а функцию написал самую простую, что бы выводила какие-то значения, но не важно какая функция, у меня ошибка с typedef

Comment: а зачем тогда в этом примере QCoreApplication и cout? Неужели вас не смутило, что нигде не фигурирует указатель? Может здесь подразумевалось `using Func = int (int, int); Func * p_func{&test};` Тогда typedef вообще не нужен, можно написать просто `auto p_func{&test};`, а лучше `auto p_func{::std::addressof(test)};`, или даже вместо указателя использовать ссылку на функцию `auto & func{test};`

Comment: QCoreApplication ничего не дает в этом примере, просто пишу в qt и там сразу функция main с QCoreApplication, я просто его не убрал, а cout, что бы на консоли было видно, запустилась функция или нет.

Comment: а написать хочу именно с typedef, поэтому если можете, то подскажите что не так с typedef, аналогичные варианты сейчас не интересуют

Comment: Единственная проблема с typedef - это использование `typedef` вместо `using`, настоящая проблема в `Func func1; func1 = test(c,b);` func1 тут - предварительное объявление функции.

Comment: ну я могу написать конкретно этот запуск функции с typedef? если да, то как?

Comment: я уже написал выше...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Примерно так](https://ideone.com/rV8Yte):

```
typedef int (*Func) (int, int);
int test (int c, int b);
int qest (int c, int b);

...

Func func1;

...

if (b > 5) 
    func1 = test;
else
    func1 = qest;

func1(c,b);
```

Comment: Спасибо, что не стали предлагать аналогичные варианты и подобное, а сразу показали мою ошибку!

Comment: Стоп, это не совсем то, что я хотел реализовать. Мы сейчас просто изменили название функции test, а я хочу просто её вызывать не test(c,b), а к примеру func1.

Comment: Ничего подобного. Здесь нет переименования. Мы присвоили переменной `func1` адрес функции `test` и вызвали ее - уже не напрямую, а через переменную. Сейчас набросаю немного более сложный пример, чтоб вам это стало очевидно - см. ответ. Видите? Мы вызываем `func1`, но какая именно будет при этом вызвана функция - `test` или `qest` - решается на основании значения `b`.

Comment: Да, все, я понял. Спасибо.

Comment: я видел typedef записанный так "#typedef double TypeFunc(double, double,double);". Какая разница между таким и записанным со скобками и указателем ?

Comment: Наверное, все же без `#`? Ну, его можно использовать для объявления функции - не `int test (int c, int b);`, а `Func test;`, или, скажем, в сочетании с `*` - `Func *func1 = test;`... Надо посмотреть, как он использовался там, где вы его видели. Просто это уже не указатель, а просто функция.

Comment: ну выходит если писать без скобок и указателя, то выйдет просто изменение названия функции? точнее функцию можно будет вызвать по 2 названиям, верно?

Comment: Да не сможете вы после этого присвоить `Func f; f = test;` - все равно через указатели придется работать.

Comment: а как передать массив в функцию данным способом ?

Comment: Как обычно - как указатель, например...